# Boundary conditions for two homogeneous rods welded together. (Heat equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The question goes as follows;

Two homogeneous rods have the same cross section, specific heat *c*, and density $\rho$  but different heat conductivities $k_1$ and $k_2$. The rods are welded together so that the temperature $u$ and heat flux $ku_x$ are continuous. The left-hand rod has its left end maintained at temperature $T1$. The right-hand rod has its right end maintained at temperature $T2$ degrees.

At t = 0 the temperature $u_1(x,0)=0$ for $0<x<1$ and $u_2(x,0)=0$ for $1<x<2$. Determine $u_1(x,t)$ and $u_2(x,t)$.

The boundary conditions at $x=1$ follow from continuity, as stated in the question. However, I do need boundary conditions at $x=0$ and $x=2$. This is where I get confused. The question states that the ends are maintained at $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively, but the initial conditions state that the temperature at $t=0$ equals $0$.

What are the correct boundary conditions? And how to solve the problem (I was thinking about Neumann or Dirichlet methods)?

Comment: As stated, the boundary and initial conditions are incompatible. There are techniques to work around this, generally either based on finding a weak solution, or based on finding a strong solution to a "close" problem (one where the boundary condition is initially compatible with the initial condition and then rapidly changed to the desired boundary condition). Such weak solution techniques *can* actually be done using separation of variables...if the boundary conditions are nice enough. (For example, I have previously solved the problem $u_t=u_{xx},u(x,0)=0,u(0,t)=0,u(1,t)=1$.)

Comment: (Cont.)   I'm not so sure that this "weld" boundary condition is nice enough for that to work. Because if you think about it, if you had already solved for $u_2$, then you would have a time-dependent Robin condition in the problem for $u_1$. Time-dependent BCs tend to be fairly difficult to handle analytically.